# Variable $id of type ID! was provided invalid value Shopify

Tags: reactjs, react-router, shopify, react-router-dom

I'm working with react to create the storefront of a shopify store. I'm trying to create the `ProductDetailsPage` but I have some problem with routing here. I have this error after fetching:

> 'Variable $id of type ID! was provided invalid value'.

This is the route I wrote:

```
<Route
  path='/product-details-page/:id'
  element={<ProductDetailPage client={client} />}
/>
```

And this is my `ProductDetailPage`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProductDetailsPage = ({ client }) => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null)

  useEffect(
    (id) => {
      client.product
        .fetch(id)
        .then((fetchedProduct) => {
          setProduct(fetchedProduct)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error fetching product:', error)
        })
    },
    [client, id]
  )

  if (!product) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{product.title}</h1>
      <p>{product.description}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductDetailsPage
```

Comment: What route are you visting? Ie: what is the value of `id` when you get this error. Based on this related question, it looks like it needs to be a specific format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73569891/variable-id-of-type-id-was-provided-invalid-value-graphql-api-shopify-no

Answer (score -1):

The `useEffect` hook's callback function is masking the `id` variable by declaring one of its own. `useEffect` doesn't pass any arguments to its callback. In other words, `id` is undefined in the hook callback function.

Instead of

```js
const { id } = useParams(); // <-- id reference #1

useEffect(
  (id) => { // <-- function arg declared, id reference #2
    client.product
      .fetch(id) // <-- #2 undefined
      .then((fetchedProduct) => {
        setProduct(fetchedProduct);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error fetching product:', error);
      });
  },
  [client, id]
);
```

Use

```js
const { id } = useParams(); // <-- id in outer scope

useEffect(
  () => {
    client.product
      .fetch(id) // <-- reference id of the outer scope, defined (hopefully)
      .then((fetchedProduct) => {
        setProduct(fetchedProduct);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error fetching product:', error);
      });
  },
  [client, id]
);
```